# Fortigate administrative overrides - how to include all subdomains?

Tags: proxy, webfilter, utm, fortigate

I need a nudge in the right direction with this:

**Situation:**
I got Fortigate device with FortiOS4.0 with enabled FortiGuard web filter. I block a category, let's say "freeware download" (example).
Now, sites that - FortiGuard decides - serve freeware download are blocked. However, I want to permit one specific, say "somefreewaresite.com" for all users. So I enter administrative override for domain somefreewaresite.com, with scope "profile" (whole profile), allowed off-site links.

Now, somefreewaresite.com is accessible. However, "www.somefreewaresite.com" is still blocked. I could add another override, but this site also uses bunch of other subdomains (down1.somefreewaresite.com, images.somefreewaresite.com). I want to permit **ALL** subdomains of "somefreewaresite.com". I tried to add wildcarded override (*.somefreewaresite.com), but subdomains still keep getting blocked!

**Question:

How to add administrative override for domain and ALL its subdomains?**

I'm sure I am missing some small detail, thanks to all for help.

Answer (score 1):

So, after research and consulting Fortinet support, I know the solutions.

It needs to be done wia URL filter.
You need to head to UTM > URL filter, add a filter and for required domain add select "**Exempt**" (not "Allow") for action.

If you enter "somefreewaresite.com", then all subdomains are permitted too.